# Quantization of EM field

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, fourier-transform, second-quantization

Usually the first step to quantization of EM field is the Fourier expansion of vector potential: 
$$ A = \sum_k A_k e^{jkr} .$$ 
For example, in book "The classical theory of fields" by Landau, Lifshitz, it is written that "we can expand all quantities
characterizing the field in this parallelepiped in a triple Fourier series" (parallelepiped is volume, where EM field exist), but still we have transform of **A**. The thing is that I've never seen a paper/book, where authors use another characteristic of the field for it ($\varphi$ or **$E$** for example). Is there any hidden meaning of this situation or it is all about computational convenience?

Comment: Other things are also Fourier-transformed, you just haven't got enough experience. The main advantage in considering Fourier harmonics is that $\vec{A}_{\vec{k}}(t)$ have the equations of motion like a simple harmonic oscillator, whom we know how to quantize.

Comment: Because $\bf E$ & $\bf B$ can be obtained from $\bf A$ through Maxwell 's equations. And using $\bf A$ gives some gauge freedom to solve problem in a more easy way. Also, in a covariant form, $\varphi$ together with the vector potential $\bf A$ forms the four-potential

Comment: @rnels12: Any function of $\vec{x}$ can be Fourier-transformed, whatever its equation is. The field strengths are "obtained" from $\bf{A}$ via definitions, not via Maxwell equations.

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski Yeah, I know about FT, but the guy's wondering why he's "never seen a paper/book, where authors use another characteristic of the field for it (φ or E for example)". Because that's how conventionally most people tackle EM problems, using $\bf A$ which gives gauge freedom

Comment: @rnels12: In Akhiezer-Berestetsky QED textbook there are all quantities Fourier-transformed, so it is lack of experience, not the gauge freedom, who is "responsible" for this question. By the way, the gauge freedom makes quantization ambiguous, so it is not an advantage.

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski Ok, I realize, that there is lack of my experience, no doubts, just want to get confident in this question. By the way I've just came across this book yesterday, I'll try to find answers to my questions in it, thanks